# TinyMCE with GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gwt, tinymce

I am trying to use TinyMCE with GWT RichTextBox but not successful. What I get is that GWT makes Rich text area as 
#document … 
which is not a textarea in HTML sense. How to put this in TinyMCE selector and use it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a plain `<textarea>` tag create a HTML or an HTMLPanel widget and put your textarea inside.

```
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"  

<g:HTMLPanel><textarea ui:id="textareaId"></textarea></g:HTMLPanel>
```